# How to get a parent collection by filtering data in a subcollection within the parent collection in firestore?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a project with firebase, and I'm having trouble searching for a specific parent collection by filtering on one of its subcollections.

For example, when starting a trip, I must check which students (parent collection) have their presence confirmed (the going attribute must be true) and also the date of attendance should be equal to the date of the trip. How can I search for confirmed students (which would be the parent collection) when filtering data in the presence subcollection?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make these calls separately as there's no JOIN-like call in Firebase. In other words, you can't reference a document to call another.

To achieve it, you would need to consider something like querying all students who have going true and collate it will the results of the date of attendance match query.